# Save blob to file with ElectronJS

Tags: electron, blob

I'm attempting to upgrade my Electron app with no node integration and context isolation. I'm moving the file saving code from the renderer to the main process. However, I'm unable to transfer a blob to the main process.

The error message is:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned.
```

**main.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
    
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) return app.quit();
    
try {require('electron-reloader')(module);} catch (_) {}
   
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;
    
async function createWindow() {
    
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
        },
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: __dirname + '/icons/icon.icns'
    });
    
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadFile('index.html')
    
    // Open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools()    
}
    
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    
    ipcMain.handle('dialog', (event, method, params) => {
        return dialog[method](params);
    });
  
    ipcMain.handle('getPath', () => {
        app.getPath('documents');
    });
    
    ipcMain.handle('writeFile', (event, filepath, blob) => {
        var message = {};
        fs.writeFile(filepath, blob, err => {
            if (err) {
                message.text = err;
                message.title = 'Error Saving Table';
            } else {
                message.text = filepath;
                message.title = 'Table saved to';
            }
        });
        return message;
    });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    ipcRenderer,
    contextBridge
} = require("electron");
    
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    openDialog: (method, params) => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog', method, params),
    getPath: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('getPath'),
    writeFile: (filepath, blob) => ipcRenderer.invoke('writeFile', filepath, blob)
});
```

**renderer.js**

```js
function exportToExcelFile(tableID, anchorID, exportFilename) {
    let format = 'xlsx';
    let anchor = $$('#' + anchorID + '-' + format);
    ExcellentExport.convert({
            anchor: anchor[0],
            filename: exportFilename,
            format: format
        }, [{
            name: 'Sheet1',
            from: {
                table: $$('#' + tableID)[0]
            }
    }]);
    
    // Get path, open save dialog and save file
    window.electron.getPath()
        .then((appDataPath) => {
            const dialogConfig = {
                filters: [{
                    name: 'Excel',
                    extensions: ['xlsx']
                }],
                defaultPath: appDataPath + '/' + exportFilename
            };
            electron.openDialog('showSaveDialogSync', dialogConfig).then(
                filepath => {
                    if (filepath !== undefined) {
                        console.log(anchor.attr('href'));
                        fetch(anchor.attr('href'))
                            .then(res => res.blob())
                            .then(blob => {electron.writeFile(filepath, blob);
                                    })
                            .then(message => {app.dialog.alert(message.text, message.title);
                            })
                    }
                }
            );
        })
        .catch(result => console.log(result));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a Blob from renderer to main through IPC, before doing that you have to convert it to ArrayBuffer.

And to be able to write that ArrayBuffer into file system once you received it on main you have to convert it to Node.js's global Buffer.

```
// renderer
const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
ipcRenderer.send('save-blob', arrayBuffer)
```

```
// main
const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)
fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer)
```

(you could also use the FileReader API to convert the ArrayBuffer to Buffer directly from the renderer process before sending it to main, so it could be written to file system directly)